# Splunk and Winston for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, splunk, winston

I am trying to use winston-splunk, to show the logs, in the splunk.
Somehow I am unable to see the logs.
I am totally new to both splunk and winston, here is my code:

```
   var splunk  = require('winston-splunk').splunk;
   var transport = new (splunk)({splunkHostname: 'localhost'});
   transport.log("error","er","This is the error message",function(err,res){
       console.log(err+"  "+res);
    })
```

How can I show this message on splunk? I also created an http event collector, to use to token, but was unable to.
Can someone guide me the right way?
How can I configure and setup my environment, if there is any code example it will be great help.
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

`winston-splunk` actually doesn't have support for HTTP Event Collector - only UDP. You'll want to use `winston-splunk-httplogger`. You can see an example on [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/adrianhall/winston-splunk-httplogger).

Comment: This library not maintained anymore :/